# python variable input custom function calling

Tags: function, python-3.x, variables, calling-convention

I am trying to call functions from a user input, but I am struggling to figure out how. For instance, if I run the program and enter `"3* foo"`, I expect a return of the output `("333333333333333333")`, except I get a `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`; any thoughts?

```
def func3():
print ("333333333333333333")

command="3* foo" #command would be an input usually
f=command.split()
dic="1*":"func1", "2*":"func2", "3*":"func3"}
function_caller=(dic[f[0]])
(function_caller)()
```

error:

```
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to call a string, remove the double quotes from the value of the dictionary, it should be:

```
dic = {"1*": func1, "2*": func2, "3*": func3}
```